# Jira AD Integration - Group filter prevents user import

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jira

We have a JIRA in our company configured to connect to our Active Directory filtering users by the AD Group "JIRA Users".

This works perfectly fine, but our company has more than 1000 groups that would be imported if I don't set a filter for groups. So I set an additional filter for specific groups I want to import on a different subtree.

Not all users in group JIRA Users are in a group in this subtree I want to select for the group import.

Now the problem is, that users in a group in my import subtree are correctly importet into JIRA. But if the user only is in groups in another subtree. The user does not get importet to JIRA.

```
Base DN: OU=company-shortname,DC=companyname,DC=de

Additional Group DN: OU=Subgroup,OU=Groups
```

User filter is:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(&(memberOf=CN=JIRA User,OU=Groups,OU=company-shortname,DC=companyname,DC=de)))
```

Groupobjectfilter is:

```
(&(objectCategory=Group)(cn=*))
```

I can't go up one level on the additional group DN because then I have all 1000 groups. Ho can I set this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you solve it by 'tagging' the groups you need to import, say by adding JIRA to the description or info (Notes) field and then pointing the group search to the top level OU and using (&(objectCategory=group)(info=JIRA*)) or similar?

Comment: that would need a lot of changes in the AD structure, which I don't have control over.